# Spatie Activity Log only returns the last log. I want all logs returned.

Tags: php, laravel, controller, view, activitylog

So, I went to read all the Spatie Activity Log documentation and in there examples it only returns the most recent log (One last log). But I need to see all the Activity Log created.

```
     public function index()
    {
    $user = Auth::user(); 
    Activity()->log('Look mum, I logged something') ->causedBy($user);
    $lastActivity = Activity::all()->last();
    $lastActivity =$lastActivity->causer;
    $lastActivity->description;
    return View('hello', compact('lastActivity'));
    }
```

I think it has to do with hte Activity::all()->last(); I tried deleting the last but it won't work. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Activity** is an Eloquent model, to get all the activities you can call `Activity::all();`, it will returns a collection.

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user(); 
    activity()->log('Look mum, I logged something')->causedBy($user);

    $allActivities = Activity::all();
    return view('hello', compact('allActivities'));
}
```

Then in your **hello view**, you can loop through the collection

```
@foreach($allActivities as $activity)
{{ $activity->description }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: You're welcome, i've edited my post, the helpers functions are in lowercase : `activity()` and `view()`

Comment: Sir @OuailB I have another question posted that somehow relate to this. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016625/show-multiple-views-in-one-function-in-laravel

Comment: how to get Spatie Activity Log by  subject_type?