# Show Multiple views in one function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, view, activitylog

So, I am currently trying to make an activity log on every single move the user makes.

```
class testActivityController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
 $user = Auth::user();
 Activity('test-activity-controller')->log('I am inside test Activity 
 Controller public function index') ->causedBy($user);
  $allActivities = Activity::all();

 return View('admin.UsersActivityLog'->with('allActivities'), 
 View::testActivityview'?????);
```

the testActivityView is where I will show the textbox where users will enter information. So I have to return it, right.

The second one is I have to show the log that the user went inside that page so I have to make some functions about Activities that will be shown to the main Admin page where all User Activity ($allActivities) should be posted.

How will I be able to return the testActivityView and the UserActivityLog in one function.

Thank you very much. Please forgive the stupid naming convention. It's already 12AM here.

Comment: why don't you just create a partial/component and include it to your view file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to  create a view with sections for ease of re-use. It then allows you to compose the various section:

**layout.blade.php**

```
@yield('header')
@yield('body')
@yield('footer')
```

**combined.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('header')
    @include('header')
@stop

@section('body')
    @include('body')
@stop

@section('footer')
    @include('footer')
@stop
```

Then you call them from controller;

```
function index()
{
    return view('combined');
}
```

So in your case you create the two views: `testActivityView.blade.php` and the `UserActivityLog.blade.php` you create a combination of those two combined.blade.php and include the two others on it:

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('header')
    @include('header')
@stop

@section('body')
    @include('testActivityView')
    @include('serActivityLog')
@stop

@section('footer')
    @include('footer')
@stop
```

then on your route controller you only return combined view: `return View('combined')->with(.....`

Comment: Sir let me rephrase the question. All I want is to send the value $allActivities to the view  UserActivityLog.blade.php. How do I return it properly? Can I use two returns?

Comment: gotcha: U just need to do Return::view('UserActivityLog', compact('allActivities'));  inside compact u can send as many var as u want to the view just separate var with a comma.

Comment: What if I don't want to return the UserActivityLog. I just want to send the data to that View but I don't want to return it.

Comment: Because I have to return the testActivityView because that is the index of the function. My problem is I just need to send the value to the UserActivityLog.blade but I don't need to return it. Thank you very much for responding to me by the way. :)

Comment: Oh okay, so that will make my $allActivities global to the whole project? where will I put the logic of the $allActivities in the controller?

Comment: Create a closure-based view composer go to app/providers/AppServiceProvider and on boot method add    view()->composer('UserActivityLog', function ($allActivites){  $view->with('allActivites', Activity::all(()})    add Activity namespace at the top this way everytime u call the UserActivityLog blade the variable $allActivites will be served to the view by default . Note if u share to all routes then it might be an overkill for the app.

Comment: @JosephCarlo are we on the same page now ?

Comment: Do you know how to return multiple views? If we return multiple views will that open two views when I run it? Sorry, it might seem like a basic question but I'm still new with this.

Comment: @JosephCarlo as i said on the answer U dont need to return multiple views. U only need to design the blades on like the structure above, so u can include as many views as u want to a single combined view so when u call it on the controller the combined view will spill the other views as well.

Comment: anyways I strongly suggest you to read the Laravel documentation on laravel.com since u new to this, that way u dont get confused fast. I hope my answers were useful please mark the answer if u think so!